# VirtualizingWrapPanel with groupping

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, user-interface, virtualization

I need to present many elements in `ListBox` with `WrapPanel` as an `ItemsPanel` with usage of groupping items and virtualization.

Everything must look like Windows 8 main page(with tiles), so:

1. Groups are placed horizontally one next to another
2. Items in groups are in WrapPanel which needs to be virtualized beceause of large items count (around 10.000 items)
3. items are wrapped vertically (take all existing vertical place and than go right, `Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal`) so no `VerticalScrollBar` is shown, just 1 `HorizontalScrollBar` for entire `ListBox`

Built in `WrapPanel` doesn't come with virtualization.

I've already tried many "VirtualizingWrapPanels" which are available for free and none of it works good with grouping. In fact, none of them is working good even without groupping but let's skip it.

Do You know any walkaround for getting those features?

Answer (score 1):

I have something better than a workaround for your problem. I can provide you with clear explanations and instructions of how to implement your own `VirtualizingPanel`. However, I should warn you that, whilst possible, it is no easy feat and will take some time. I have scucessfully implemented my own `VirtualizingAnimatedPanel` using this same information source, so it certainly can be done.

Of course, this topic is far too large to cover here, so for full details about virtualization and how to implement it, please read chapter 8 of the very useful WPF Control Development Unleashed book. Luckily for you, I found an online copy of this book, so you can read it now:

[WPF Control Development Unleashed](http://www.adorkable.us/books/wpf_control_development.pdf)

Comment: It's a great book and I am reading it now, thank You very much. Despite of fact that I've read 8th chapter and I have my own knowledge about it I still don't know how to combine Groupping and Virtualization :/

Comment: Just restructure your data type classes to be hierarchical, eg. make it so that each item in the collection represents a group that has children.

Comment: i have found that pdf version, but is this legal ?

Comment: also that the virtualizingwrappanel work with grouping ? that would be awesome :)

Comment: @user2475096, no I doubt that the PDF that you found is legal.